# redash can’t login to redash after enabling REDASH_MULTI_ORG

Tags: redash

redash can’t login to redash after enabling REDASH_MULTI_ORG

couldn’t find any documentation about setting up a multi organisation

What I want to achieve is that each user's data source is independent, how should I achieve this?

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.